# Windows Phone 8.1 custom controls

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I'm developing Windows Phone 8.1 application and I want to use data visualization. I found WinRT XAML Toolkit as a solution, but I don't know how to use this. Can anyone tell the full instructions?

I've tried this way:

1)Package Manager Console: Install-Package WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.WindowsPhone

2)In Visual Studio 2013 toolbox right click->add tab->right click inside tab->choose items->open dll file from my project packages folder.

When I do this I can see new controls in toolbox, but I can't use, because when I drag control to my activity there appears empty box. And also icons of controls are the same.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Nuget to install this package, after adding the package, you could see it in your reference list.

Refer to the WinRT XAML Toolkit in nuget page: https://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit/.

Comment: Thank you, I was blind, now I get it